# Conditionally Formatting a cell, based on cells including formulas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight a cell A6, if B6 + C6 >74.9%.  However, B6 and C6 are calculated values and conditional formatting reads the formula in the cell, not the value it calculates

I can create an if statement with a `1` or a `0`:

```
=if((B6+C6) > 0.749, 1,0)
```

but if I use the same if statement in the conditional formatting (with out the `,1,0`) nothing happens:

```
=if(b6+C6) > 0.749
```

I want the cell to turn green, rather than a `1` or a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the formula you're using is wrong. In the conditional format formula you don't need an IF statement at all, you can just write out the condition, which evaluates to either TRUE or FALSE.

In this case it's

```
=B6+C6>0.749
```

[image]

For completion's sake: if you wanted to write a full IF statement, then it would have to look like

```
=if(B6+C6>0.749,true, false)
```

Comment: I did try that intially.  It did not work.  That's why i started playing with if statements to compare to conditional formatting.  Did you type in the 0.5 and 0.3 or did you use a formula to calculate?

Comment: IE.  B6 is the average of B1-B5 and C6 is the average of C1-C5)

Comment: It does not make a difference. The VALUE of the cells is taken into consideration, not how that value is arrived at. I just mocked it up again and now I have formulas in B6 and C6. The CF still works.

Comment: use an ad-free file sharing service like Dropbox or OneDrive to share a sample file. Post a link in a comment.

Comment: Have you tried any troubleshooting? For e.g. put the formula `=B6+C6>0.749` into a worksheet cell. What does it return? TRUE or FALSE? What is the result of the formula `=B6+C6` ??  You need to inspect the elements that go into the conditional format to figure out what is not working.